# Mount a USB drive at runtime with root access

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have an Android device with root access which always has a USB memory stick attached to it on the same USB port. The problem is that it is never mounted when the device starts and my application needs to access the files on that disk.

Now I have to mount it manually through `settings` every time the device starts,
before I can start my app. Isn't there a way to do it at runtime through code?

I've looked into applications such as StickMount by Chainfire, but they don't seem to mount the USB.

Comment: If `StickMount` does not work, what makes your think you can make it working? If your device has root access try mount it manually through the terminal. If you can do this, then you should be able to exactly the same in your app by firing the same commands.

Comment: I have no idea how StickMount works exactly. Anyway will try to use the mount command as you suggested, I'm guessing that should work since I can mount it using the settings. Thnx for the tip, will update with the results